# bootstrap fixed to top but below alert at top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'am trying to have an alert at the top of my page with a form for my visitors to put in their phone number. It is simply a "alert alert-info" div with the form within it. So that works great because I put it at the top of my body tag. Then comes the nav, which right now is a "navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" div. When I try to change that into a fixed-top (fixed below the alert) it just comes out on top of the alert (There might be a z-index issue, I don't know). Does anyone know how I can make the nav fixed at the top but below the alert (which should be static at the very top)?

Thanks alot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers. Found the final answer my self (from another question here) using the bootstrap affix.
I put an id to the alert called "alert" and an id to the nav called "topnavbar". I then added the css:

```
#topnavbar {
margin: 0;
}
#topnavbar.affix {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

and the javascript:

```
$('#topnavbar').affix({
offset: {
top: $('#banner').height()
}   
});
```

From: [Putting content/banner above the "Fixed Top Navbar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028299/putting-content-banner-above-the-fixed-top-navbar)

This put the nav between the alert and jumbotron and the nav becomes sticky after the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Per Bootstrap's [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar): "The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the body."

Comment: DavidBrown, thanks for your answer. I might be missing something but I am well aware of this but can't really see how this would help in this case as my layout should look like this: Alert-Fixed Nav-Jumbotron. This helps in the case where the Nav comes first, then the alert and jumbotron. The fixed nav should be between the alert and the jumbotron.

Comment: Can you share a URL so we can see the issue?

Answer (score -1):

If I get what you want to do, why not try something like this.
Just add another div container **in** .. but at the **top of the navbar**.
And just place you alert in this container.
Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/bdp6uc22/8/)**.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container col-lg-12 bg-primary"><br><br></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```