# Static Nav Bar with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I want to make the Menu Bar stick to the top when the user scrolls.  I used to use Bootstrap's class called 'navbar-fixed-top' and it works fine.

But the user wants to add some brands and logos above the Nav bar.  But they don't want those logos to stick to the top when the user scrolls.  They want to stick only the Nav bar below those logos.

I tried to use 'navbar-fixed-top' but it appears on the Logos instead of below the Logos.

[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="col-md-12 text-left">
        // Code for Logos and Images
    </nav>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>.....</li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

How can I make the nav-bar stick to the top (not the logos)?

Comment: Possible Solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028299/putting-content-banner-above-the-fixed-top-navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove navbar-fixed-top from NAV tag and put this code in head tag

```
    <script>
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var height = $(window).scrollTop();
            if(height  <= 100) {
                $("nav").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
            }
            if(height  <= 10) {
                $("nav").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
            }
        });
    </script>
```